# Hi Im getting the swift error = Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'labelText'

Tags: swift, segue

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Share" {

         var destViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! UITableViewController).tableView   //Warning
        destViewController.labelText = TEXT.text! 
       //Error = Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'labelText'


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting that error is pretty self-explanatory: there is no defined variable "labelText" in the UITableViewController class. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code? It is very ambiguous. If you were more clear about what you were trying to do, providing an answer for you would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use textLabel instead of labelText